# Show MySQL vector data on QGIS canvas

Tags: qgis, python, mysql-spatial

I am a novice to Python and QGIS coding. I am facing an issue while showing the MySQL spatial data on QGIS canvas. Database connection details are below:

```
database name:- mysql
host :- localhost
port :- 3306
user :- root
password :- abcx
tablename:- Tablegis
```

I found a code on to connect the same:

```
uri="MySQL:mysql,host=localhost,port=3306,user=root,password=abcx|layername=Tablegis"
vlayer=QGSVectorLayer(uri, "Open_Table","ogr")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

This code doesn't show any warning or error but nothing shows on my canvas. When I am printing the vlayer shows the object reference. Tried hard nothing worked for me.

Comment: does the layer display if you add it manually using the menus

Comment: Nothing on the canvas but can you access the content of the **attribute table** ? Are you sure of the geographical content of your table ?

Comment: Yes Ian, when I am manually adding the MySQL table in QGIS it displays and can also see the attributes.

Comment: code is okay, i am just missing the update extent and zoom the canvas to objects of table.